# Execute a command using a filename from the vim buffer

Tags: vim, gvim, text-editing

I'm working with some [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org)-like files.  The files have companion PNG files in the same directory.  They're referenced in the following syntax:

```
{{filename.png}}
```

I want to write a macro which would take the `filename.png` and ideally the path of the file being edited, and pass these parameters to `xdg-open`.

The closest I've managed so far is this:

```
:'<,'>!sed s/\{\\\|\}//g|xargs xdg-open
```

which is crude, obliterates the current line, requires me to be in the path of the file and requires me to use visual mode to highlight the text.... but it does work.

I'm having trouble finding documentation which can help me safely parse the current line for the filename, then pass the path of the current file and the target filename to `xdg-open` on the vim command line.

When done... this would ideally let me launch the macro to view the embedded file.

---

Per G-Man's answer and some fiddling, the following works well:

```
:.w !sed -e 's|.*{{|%{{|' -e 's|[^/]*{{||' -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/}}.*/"/' | xargs xdg-open
```

This inserts double quote (`"`) characters at the beginning and end
of the path/filename, so it supports names that include spaces,
apostrophes (single quotes), and some other special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ```
  :range!command
  ```

  writes the text from the *range* to a pipe (deleting it from the file buffer),
  runs the *command* on the pipe, reads the standard output of the command
  and inserts it into the buffer where the *range* was. 
  That’s the `vim` function that you are using. 
  This function is very useful with the `sort` command. 
  I can’t recall ever seeing any other situation
  where this `vim` function is useful; this doesn’t seem to be one.

  You want

  ```
  :range w !command
  ```

  which
  writes the *range* to a pipe (but doesn’t delete it from the file buffer),
  runs the *command* on the pipe,
  and lets the standard output of the command (if any)
  just go to the screen (i.e., `vim`’s standard output). 
  (The space between the *range* and the **`w`** is optional.)
- The *range* can be from one mark to another
  (`'<` and `'>` are effectively marks),
  one line to another, or just a single line. 
  As long as you have only one `{{…}}` on a line,
  you can just go to the line (you don’t need to highlight it)
  and use **`.`** as your range. 
  If you have only one `{{…}}` in the file,
  you can use `/{{.*}}/` (or even `/{{/`, if that’s unique) as your range. 
  So your command becomes

  ```
  :/{{/w !sed blah blah blah
  ```
- I prefer to quote strings that need quoting *with quotes*,
  rather than by throwing a million backslashes at them. 
  I guess that’s just a personal preference;
  if backslashes work for you, use them.
- Fancy regular expressions
  (using `|` to search for one pattern or another)
  have their place in the world. 
  I lean toward using multiple `sed` commands. 
  Again, whatever.
- So my version of what you’re doing now would look something like this:

  ```
  :/{{/w !sed -e 's/.*{{//' -e 's/}}.*//' | xargs xdg-open
  ```

  which removes the `{{` and everything before it,
  and removes the `}}` and everything after it. 
  But this still requires you to be in the directory where the PNG file is.
- The PNG file is in the same directory as the text file. 
  It is useful to note that,
  when you run a shell command with `!` from `vim`,
  an unescaped `%` in the command line
  is replaced by the name of the file you’re currently editing. 
  (Try it: type `:!echo abc%def`.) 
  We can use this to determine the pathname
  to the directory where the files are. 
  So we can improve the above command to:

  ```
  :/{{/w !sed -e 's|.*{{|%{{|' -e 's|[^/]*{{||' -e 's|}}.*||' | xargs xdg-open
  ```

  The first sed subcommand, `s|.*{{|%{{|`,
  removes everything before the `{{` and replaces it with the filename,
  *and leaves the* `{{`. 
  Note that this subcommand *must* use a (non-blank) delimiter
  that will not appear in the path/filename, so we can’t use `/`. 
  If you have directory names or filenames with vertical bars in them,
  pick some other character to use as your delimiter. 
  The second subcommand, `s|[^/]*{{||`,
  removes the *filename portion* of the `%` filename,
  leaving the directory portion (if any), and removes the `{{`. 
  The third subcommand, `s|}}.*||`,
  is the same as the second subcommand (`s/}}.*//`) from the previous command;
  it removes the `}}` and everything after it.

  While `s/pattern/replacement/` commands
  always need to use a delimiter that doesn’t appear
  in the *`pattern`* or the *`replacement`* text
  (or escape the delimiter character when it does appear),
  this is an issue only for the first **`s`** command. 
  I used `|` in all three just for consistency.

#### TL;DR

Use:

```
:/{{/w !sed -e 's|.*{{|%{{|' -e 's|[^/]*{{||' -e 's|}}.*||' | xargs xdg-open
```

P.S. I assume that you realize that these won’t work
if the filename contains space(s).

Comment: this is helpful on so many levels.   Per your extra info, I got it working properly, with spaces in directory paths and filenames.   I'll add the new command in an edit.